# How to make a I vi iii progression sound like IV ii i

Tags: scales

I am trying to write a song that incorporates a tonally ambiguous chord progression and a tonally ambiguous melody. I like the sound of G > Em > Bm > Bm. How can I write a melody to this to imply that it is Bm without actually using the key notes (C#) that might give the listener the satisfaction of pinning my key progression down. I have two measures of Bm at the end so that kind of helps but I need more. I have an idea but not sure if it will work. For example, if I was to end the phrase of the melody on the Bm chord using the F# note then wouldn't that eliminate G as an option for the tonal center since F# in G is the leading tone and would want to be resolved upward to G.

Comment: How did C# become a key note of B minor?

Comment: To clarify: you want to write a melody line that suggests underlying harmony without actually providing any chordal accompaniment?

Comment: @Tim If you have a chord progression such as in the OP they come from G major or D major (B minor natural). Using C# in the melody would remove the ambiguity.

Comment: @user1079505 I want to write a melody that uses notes and chords that will define 2 possible tonal centers of that part of the song but I still want the chord progression to sound like it is in Bm not G major. I was hoping what notes I choose to end the melody with can help define the Bm sound more than G major without having to resort to the obvious use of the C# note which would clearly give the game away

Comment: Would you call A# a key note that gives away the game, since it's the leading tone of Bm?

Comment: @armani Do you mean something like Sweet Home Alabama? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DVPq_-oJV5U

Comment: @Dekkadeci It would be in harmonic minor but I am just looking at the standard diatonic major scale / natural minor for the melody, not the harmonic minor as that has its distinct sound.

Comment: @user1079505  Yes kind of like that. If you notice in the song sweet home alabama it is in G not in D... people get confused by it but it is obvious by which the rest notes in the melody are. they fall on the G chord not the D chord and they are the stable tones of the G major chord... this is how the ear hears tonality IMO :) So I was thinking if my melody ends on the B chord using the B minor chord tones then the ear will hear B minor more than G major . This is the way I see it but I am trying to write a song this way to prove it to myself :)

Comment: I'm not sure that the melody would be enough.  Are you open to an ostinato including but not limited to the notes B and D?